# search form - does not show the content of the page

Tags: php, html, mysqli

that's how I started to do a "search form", it should be such that one is looking after *Fitnessdk* and *nordsjælland* so all come forward,

The problem is that right now it is such that it will not come up with it as I was searching for.

**Php** :

```
if(isset($_POST["sognu"]))
{
    if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare('SELECT fms_opslag.id, fms_opslag.title, fms_opslag.undertitle, fms_opslag.fitness, fms_opslag.landsdel, fms_opslag.brugerid, fms_bruger.profilbillede FROM fms_opslag INNER JOIN fms_bruger ON fms_opslag.brugerid=fms_bruger.id WHERE fitness LIKE "%".$fitness."%" AND landsdel LIKE "%".$landsdel."%" ORDER BY fms_opslag.tidspunkt DESC'))
    { 
        $stmt->bind_param('ss', $fitness, $landsdel);
        $fitness = $_post["fitness"];
        $landsdel = $_post["omrade"];
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($id, $title, $undertitle, $fitness, $landsdel, $brugerid, $profilbillede);
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        ?>
        <tr class="postbox">
            <td>
                <a href="/profil/<?php echo $brugerid;?>/"><img src="/profil-img/smaa/<?php echo $profilbillede;?>"></a>
            </td>
            <td class="tabletitle">
                <h3><?php echo $title;?></h3>
                <p><?php echo $undertitle;?></p>
                <?php
                if($_SESSION["login"] == true)
                {
                ?>
                <form action="/ansog/<?php echo $id;?>/" method="post">
                    <input type="submit" name="ansoge" value="Ansøg nu" class="kliknuBB">
                </form>
                <?php
                }
                ?>
            </td>
            <td class="tableomrade">
                <p><?php echo $fitness;?></p>
            </td>
            <td class="tablemap">
                <p><?php echo $landsdel;?></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        }
        $stmt->close();

    }
}
```

**html form**:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
<div id="search-top">
    <div class="infobarindhold">
        <p>Fitness center</p>
        <select name="fitness" class="bar">
        <?php
            if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare('SELECT navn FROM fms_fitness')) { 
                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->bind_result($navn);
                while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $navn;?>"><?php echo $navn;?></option>
                <?php
                }
                $stmt->close();
            }
        ?>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="infobarindhold">
        <p>Placering</p>
        <select name="omrade" class="bar">
          <?php
                if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare('SELECT navn FROM fms_landsdel')) { 
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $stmt->bind_result($navn);
                    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                    ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $navn;?>"><?php echo $navn;?></option>
                    <?php
                    }
                    $stmt->close();
                }
            ?>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="cl"></div>
</div>
<div id="sogbar">
    <input type="submit" name="sognu" value=" " class="sognu">
    <div class="cl"></div>
</div>
```

It is such that there will be no content appears on the page.

Comment: JFYI, a question like "please read my code, formulate a question and answer it as well" considered quite offtopic.

Comment: @YourCommonSense What you mean on its?

Comment: your form is sending to # ? change to PHP's script

Comment: @przeqpiciel What should I write in there?

Comment: I mean you are supposed to debug your code yourself, instead of asking community to do it for you.

Comment: my error say : Error on: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.$fitness."%" AND landsdel LIKE "%".$landsdel."%" ORDER BY fms_opslag.tidspunkt ' at line 1

Comment: @Jesperbook, are you solve your problem ? About mysql syntax you probably use this: fitness LIKE \'%'.$fitness.'\' AND landsdel LIKE \'%'.$landsdel.'%\'